# How do I resend user input after a command (e.g. User: !send 1234 Bot: 1234) in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have recently started programming my own discord bot as many other people are doing...
So far what I have got is this:

```
@bot.command
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content.startswith("t!send"):
       await client.send_message(message.content)
```

It doesn't crash but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, questions are posed as Minimal, Reproducible Examples. What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried `message.channel.send(message.content)`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you're using a tutorial for an old version of discord.py.
There are some [big changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) in the most recent version - rewrite. Please take some time to look for more updated tutorials, or read the documentation linked above.

Here are the cases for using both the `on_message` event and commands:

```py
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *, sentence):
    await ctx.send(sentence)

######################################

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith("t!send"):
        await message.channel.send(" ".join(args))
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message) # only add this if you're also using command decorators
```

---

**References:**

- [`commands.Context()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) - if not familiar with using command decorators
- [`discord.on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

Comment: still doesn't work, It doesn't crash but it doesn't work either...

Comment: @Vila would you mind editing your question with the code you wrote? As well as any errors you've gotten. Also, which version of discord.py are you using? `print(discord.__version__)` to find out. Side-note, don't accidentally leak your token.

Answer (score -1):

So first of all, on_message doesn't belong here and you also don't have to use it. (`on_message()` would use the decorator `@bot.event`) Assuming you have setup a prefix for your bot using `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 't!')` you could do something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *args):
   message = " ".join(args)
   await ctx.send(message)
```

*args is everything the user types in after t!send. So for example: if the user types in t!send Hello world! args would be `["Hello", "world!"]`. With `.join` we can join them together into a single string (`message`)